# Android version of NSNotificationCenter (event binding)

Tags: android, events, callback, android-lifecycle

Is there a way in android to bind to an activity's lifecycle events? I'm making a library and I'd like to hook into onCreate etc. The iOS version of the lib does it like this:

```
- (void)observe
{
    [self bindAppEvent:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification toMethod:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActiveHandler:)];
    [self bindAppEvent:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification toMethod:@selector(applicationWillResignActiveHandler:)];
    [self bindAppEvent:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification toMethod:@selector(applicationWillTerminateHandler:)];
}

#pragma mark Private Methods

- (void)bindAppEvent:(NSString *)appEvent toMethod:(SEL)aSelector
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
            addObserver:self
               selector:aSelector
                   name:appEvent
                 object:app];
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) to register your own callbacks to activity life-cycle events.

Requirements:

- API level 14.
- Your library need a reference the the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) to register the callbacks.